# Cómo leer un JSON desde Java

Tags: php, java, json

Hola estoy intentando leer un JSON que me devuelve valores de una base de datos, que lo género desde un archivo.php.

Ahora ¿Como puedo hacer para obtener el JSON que me devuelve mi archivo.php? que se encuentra en mi servidor localhost. El servidor lo monte en WAMP.

Código PHP

```
<?php 
$servidor="localhost"; 
$nombre_bd="test2"; 
$username="root"; 
$password=""; 
$conexion = mysql_connect($servidor, $username, $password) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos"); 
mysql_select_db($nombre_bd, $conexion) or die ("Se ha producido un error al seleccionar la base de datos"); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conexion); 
$array = array(); 
$i = 0; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $array[$i] = $row; 
    $i ++; 
} 
$json = json_encode($array); echo $json; ?>
```

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Puedes añadir lo que llevas realizado?

Comment: Hola hice un código sencillo que se conecta a una base de datos, y me genera un JSON de las valores de la consulta

Comment: <?php
$servidor="localhost";
$nombre_bd="test2";
$username="root";
$password="";

$conexion = mysql_connect($servidor, $username, $password) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");

  
mysql_select_db($nombre_bd, $conexion) or die ("Se ha producido un error al seleccionar la base de datos");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $conexion);

$array = array();

$i = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $array[$i] = $row;
  $i ++;
}

$json = json_encode($array);
echo $json;
?>

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es cómo obtener ese JSON del servidor desde Java.

Comment: Yo te recomiendo usar una librería llamada Gson que sirve para serializar y decodificar objetos/jsons desde java, justo lo estoy usando para un proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendaría usar una librería cliente HTTP (por ej: [Apache Http](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fluent.html), [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/)) y otra para parsear el JSON (por ej: [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/))

Por ejemplo con el cliente Apache HTTP Fluent:

```
String body = Request.Get("http://localhost/")
    .execute().returnContent().asString();

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyValue value = mapper.readValue(body, MyValue.class);
```

Por otro lado hay que definir la clase *MyValue*, que es un wrapper con los atributos:

```
public class MyValue {
  public String nombre;
  public int edad;
  ...
}
```